# Display video in Qml via Gstreamer qmlglsink plugin

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer

I'm trying the [qmlsink example](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/master/tests/examples/qt/qmlsink) with Qt 5.12.2. It import the GLVideoItem plugin with

`import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GLVideoItem 1.0`

But QtCreator always reminds Qml Module Not Found.

I have already installed Gstreamer 1.14.1 by `apt-get install` command. But i dont know where the `GLVideo` plugin is and how to add the plugin path to qmldir folder. There is little information  about `GLVideo` in Google.

Is there somebody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed the following packages: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c#install-gstreamer-on-ubuntu-or-debian ?

Comment: Yes, I just followed the command `Install GStreamer on Ubuntu or Debian` given by the Gstreamer official web.

Answer (score 0):

must install two package
`gstremer1.0-plugins-good`
`gstremer1.0-qt5`